# Не могу прочитать нужное значение поля объекта

Tags: php

Есть поле объекта, вывожу его на экран  `<?php print $prod->attributes;?>`
результат: a:1:{i:5;i:272;}
Вопрос: как мне читая $prod->attributes переменной $a присвоить значение из поля равное 5,
а переменной $b  значение из этого поля равное 272

Comment: Вопрос снимаю. Оказывается это поле является простой строкой, смутили эти двоеточия и фигурные скобки.